# Is it possible to incorporate 'the number of replicates' as a random effect?

Tags: mixed-model, unbalanced-classes

Due to the constraints of other aspects of my sample design, I have treatment categories where the number of replicates varies between, say, 17 - 70 across 15 factor levels. For my variable of interest, there is an increase in the spread of data points with the increased number of replicates, which leads to difficulty in comparing between factor levels where the underlying number of replicates is very different – however, I do not want to lose data by randomly selected 17 replicates from all treatments.

As such, the solution that has presented itself would be to include the number of replicates as a random effect with a mixed-effect model, or to weight the model by this abundance. At the risk of sounding uninformed – is it possible to do this, and/or how would you best recommend going about it?

(I don’t necessarily mean within the specifics of a statistical approach, but a suggestion for a general methodology that might include some inherent ability to offset or weight by the number of replicates (rather attempting to force it to recognise a variable called ‘number of replicates’ as just that, which I have not had much success with, previously)).